# Toggle PCI device between host and guest with a PCI passthrough

Tags: linux

**Situation:**
I have one 144hz monitor and would like to be able to play games on Windows and Linux (Fedora) using a PCI passthrough without rebooting.

**Question:**
Since I only have one competent GPU and on board graphics I was wondering if there would be a way to toggle the assignment of that PCI from host to guest and vice versa? Or have it just so when the Windows machine is on my Linux is redirected to my HDMI?

```
+----------------+
|                |
|                |
|     Host       |
|                +--------+
|                |        |           +--------------------+
|                |        |           |                    |
+----------------+        |           |                    |
                          |           |                    |
                          |           |                    |
                          Toggle------+      Display       |
                          |           |                    |
                          |           |                    |
+----------------+        |           |                    |
|                |        |           +--------------------+
|                |        |
|     Guest      |        |
|                +--------+
|                |
|                |
+----------------+
```

Comment: An interesting question. I have no definite answer (so posting this as a comment), but I do not know of any way under windows to release the card. (Linux should be able to boot without is using a PCI-e stub).

Comment: Which OS is the host? If it's a recent fedora release as host then this is doable with a Windows guest running in a qemu/kvm virtual machine.

Comment: I'm running Fedora as the host. So it would be going from Fedora then dropping the PCI for the Windows KVM/QEMU.